# How to test for effect of Binary variable on multiple dependent variables Is T test okay?

Tags: r, t-test, binary-data

Hello I am trying to test the effect of a treatment type on multiple variables.

Basically I have two different types of sites Site A had Harvest A and Site B had a B type Harvest.

I went to multiple Sites where Harvest type A was conducted and multiple Sites where Harvest B was conducted. I collected data on the slope and condition of roads at these sites. I now want to compare how the slope and conditions of roads differs among Harvest Type A and Harvest Type B

I am Using R

Is a t test good to use to compare each slope or road condition to harvest type?
The code I’m using looks like

```
t.test(Slope data~ harvest type, data = harvestsites) 
t.test(Road condition data~ harvest type, data = harvestsites)
```